# How to run a java serial data command with arguments on start-up

Tags: boot, serial, java, serial-console, upstart

I am using Raspberry Pi 2 to a telosB base station to collect data from other sensors. I receive (on the terminal) hex data and redirect these incoming data into a python script which will clean and upload to mysql.

Manually (steps i take to do the task:)

1. `source ~/.bashrc`
2. `source ~/.tinyos.sh`
3. `java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB:telosb | python data-manager.py`

I want the raspberry pi2 (running on Rasbian) to do these steps on boot immediately.

I have tried using the update-rc.d method and the crontab method both of which do not work. I think it is because of the arguments in my command that are not going through.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one script that does it all (`.sh`) and setup cron job starting with @reboot instead of times. You probably have to do that on root user (`sudo -s`). I would rather use full path `/home/pi` (?) instead of `~` and `.` instead of `source`.

To make it persistant, use screen:

`sudo apt-get install screen`

and add to crontab something like this:

`@reboot screen -d my_autorun /home/pi/autorun.sh` <-- my_autorun is a name, can be whatever

---

Edit (2):

Look... you are doing it wrong, and I don't have enough space in comment...

You need to create new file, lets say `autorun.sh`:

Run `cat > autorun.sh` paste those lines to it:

```
cd /home/pi
./home/pi/.bashrc
./home/pi/.tinyos.sh
java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB:telosb | python data-manager.py
```

... and hit `CTRL+C` to save it.

Then run: `chmod 777 autorun.sh`

I think that to be able to listen on that serial port, you need root rights so... run: `sudo -s`

Next run: `crontab -e`

And finally add the line `@reboot screen -d my_autorun /home/pi/autorun.sh`, hit `CTRL+X` and press `Y` to save.

That should be it.

Comment: forgot to mention it has to run persistently on the background as it keeps listening to the serial port.

Comment: edited, so it would act like daemon

Comment: Apologies, i tried:

`@reboot . /home/pi/.bashrc
@reboot . /home/pi/.tinyos.sh
@reboot screen -d testscr /home/pi/script.sh`

But as soon as I restart and do 'ps fax' or 'pgrep testscr' nothing comes up

Comment: you are doing it wrong... please check latest edit... if it won't work, I can't help you, as you need basic unix knowledge and this is wrong forum for it

Comment: I did exactly as you said it. When I run `ps aux` or `pgrep 'my_autorun'` process isn't there. Checked my db, no data insertions made.

Comment: removed the whole `screen -d` part. apparently crontab works in the back process already and doesn't need to be daemonized. Now works. Thanks!